# PHP by keypress jquery

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I want to make search in my username database but it doesnt recognize keypress function. also, I want to prevent search.php on first load (can't use isset because there is no button) this is my *index.php*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <?php  include 'search.php'; ?>

  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#textbox1").keypress(function() {
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "search.php",
          success: function(data) {
            $("#main").html(data);
          }
        });
      });
    });
  </script>

  <form method="POST">
    enter keyword to search<br>
    <input type="text" name="textbox1" id="textbox1">
    <br><br>
    <div id="main"></div>
  </form>
</head>

<body>
```

This is my *search.php*. the *connection.php* is working proper. so I'm not pasting it here

```
<?php

    include 'connection.php';

    $search_value = $_POST['textbox1'];
    $query = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username LIKE '" . $search_value . "%'";
    $conn_status = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    while($row = $conn_status->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo $row['username'] . '<br>';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Please only ask **one** question per question. If you have multiple questions, ask multiple questions.

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: How do you know keypress isn't working? You aren't sending anything to your PHP so you're not gathering what was pressed. Have you checked with any of the other keyboard events?

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: @DavidStockinger but the questions are related to eachother

Comment: You likely want .`keyup()` because `.keypress()` will not give you the value you expect. It will always be one letter behind.

Comment: If you don't find a successful solution tag me in comments and i can send you some commented code with how to do this as ive done it multiple times before.

Comment: you've been given answers, one of them asked you if it works now and the other you said nothing, yet you talk to somebody else, what gives here?

Comment: why don't you tell him that then? you never answered the guy.

Comment: [This folks, is a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358600/lets-send-new-users-off-to-see-the-wizard#comment526922_358600) in a [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358600/1415724) that was created for posts just like this. Feel free to upvote that if you agree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should send the field value to your PHP page as data in your ajax request like :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "search.php",
    data: {textbox1: $(this).val()},
    success: function (data) {
          $("#main").html(data);
    }
});
```

**NOTE :** I suggest the use of `input` event in this case since it's more efficient when tracking the user input :

```
$("#textbox1").on('input', function(){
    //Your logic here
});
```

Comment: how do I prevent include file to load on first opening

Comment: What you mean by _first opening_ ?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki *"It works now ?"* - That's what I'd like to know also. I've asked the OP what was going on, but they seem dead set on not letting us all know (well, to the exception somewhat of me, under their question) why it doesn't seem to satisfy them. Lord as my witness; I tried. The question was also too broad to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet is a working one with amendments since you have wrong HTML as well as forgetting to send data to the server.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <form method="POST">
    enter keyword to search<br>
    <input type="text" name="textbox1" id="textbox1">
    <br><br>
    <div id="main"></div>
  </form>


  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $("#textbox1").on('input',function() {

        var searchText = $(this).val();
        console.log("Calling PHP with value:" + searchText);

        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          data: "textbox1=" + searchText,
          url: "search.php",
          success: function(data) {
            $("#main").html(data);
          },
          error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
          }
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```